# Put a default selected value in my select

Tags: cakephp

I have done a lot of research but I cannot find how to put a value selected by default in a select (structure cakephp).

For example: Choose a town (empty value, value = "")

That's what I tried, but I do not see "choose a town" in my select.

```
<?php
$selected = array('Choose a town' => '');
echo $this -> Form -> input('Town.name', array('label' => false, 'selected' => $selected, 'options' => array('Los Angeles' => 'Los Angeles', 'New York' => 'New York')));
?>
```

Comment: I hate downvoting but...you can easily find this in the docs or any Google search so I question that part about "I have done a lot of research".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not the default but the "empty" option:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Town.name', [
    'empty' => __('choose a town')
]);
```

Check the documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-inputs

It is explained in detail with an example there:

> When passed to a select list, this creates a blank option with an
>   empty value in your drop down list. If you want to have a empty value
>   with text displayed instead of just a blank option, pass in a string
>   to empty: